# How to create a link inside a table in Iccube 6 Reporting?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

is it possible to generate a link in a table in Iccube reporting 6?

I want to have a clickable link in a table that url is generated by a value in the table row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the time being it's not possible to set custom html to a table cell. There is a chance that corresponding cell renderer will be added in RC3, but for now you might want to use after render hook and jQuery as a workaround.

Here is [Demo Report](https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FTable%20Headers%20Labels%20%26%20Hooks%20example&mode=editing_reporting&ic3demo) with described solution